# Выборка из базы столбцов с будущими датами

Tags: php, mysql, sql, дата

Есть таблица `transfers`, в ней столбец `datefrom` формата `datetime`.
Нужно вытащить все строки, где `datefrom` больше текущей даты.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transfers WHERE who = '$id' AND DATE(datefrom) >= '$_nowdate' 
        ORDER BY datefrom DESC LIMIT 3"
```

Такой запрос выводит все записи :-(
Спасибо!

P.S. `$_nowdate = date()`;

**Обновление**

1. Все запросы проверяю в `phpmyadmin`
2. Документацию по функции `date()` читал. Не однократно. И до сих пор не понимаю как с вашей точки зрения вызывать функцию `date()` «правильно».
3. Переписал запрос так ...`AND datefrom > NOW()`....
4. Подскажите, а как, например, мне отсортировать запрос по id, который мне приходит скажем callback'ом из ajax запроса?

Comment: Попробуйте так:
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM transfers WHERE who = '$id' AND datefrom >= '$_nowdate' 
        ORDER BY datefrom DESC LIMIT 3"`

Answer (score 2):

1. Включить вывод ошибок.
2. прочитать документацию по функции date() и узнать, как ее вызывать **правильно**
3. Переписать запрос так

   ```
   AND DATE(datefrom) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY datefrom DESC LIMIT 3
   ```
4. Освоить PDO и подготовленные выражения, и больше **никогда** не подставлять переменные в запрос напрямую

Comment: Обновил вопрос.